# $wpdb->insert not working. No Error Msg

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Got the lower portion here sorted, but now there's an issue when it inserts the record. I have the `NULL` value for `file` formatted as `%s` for string, but it's not inserting `NULL` it's inserting `[BLOB - 0B]`. The column format in the mySQL table is `longblob`. Any ideas?

---

this is my first time using `$wpdb->insert` and it looks like I've missed something.

Here's the loop I'm trying to use. There are currently 2 timestamps in the array.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($timestamps); $i++ ) {
$working_time = $timestamps[$i];
$working_form = $formnames[$i];

$status_data = array(
    'submit_time' => $working_time,
    'form_name' => $working_form,
    'field_name' => 'lead_status',
    'field_value' => 'new',
    'field_order' => 10001,
    'file' => NULL
);
$status_data_types = array(
    '%f',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%d',
    '%s'
);

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT field_value FROM ".$leadtable." WHERE submit_time = ".$working_time);

if(!$result) {              
    $insert = $wpdb->insert($leadtable, $status_data, $status_data_types);
    if( !$insert ) {
            echo 'didn\'t work';
        }
}
}
```

I know that `$working_time` and `$working_form` are both set properly. `$working_time` is a long float like `1387175380.9600` and `$working_form` is a string.

Nothing is being returned, even by the `if( !$insert )` check so I'm guessing it's erring somewhere before that point. I know that `if( !$result )` will return true because that data does not exist yet.

Found the issue. The get_results query was failing due to a missed period. My HS English teacher was right... a missed period can be a HUGE problem!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe your config hides error showing. Have you tried `$wpdb->print_error();`?

Comment: yeah, all over the place. after each insert statement and inside the `if(!)` statements. It's not returning anything.

Comment: added it in a couple other places tho, and, of course, found the error. Bad query. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: Wouldn't happen to know the data format call to insert data into a column formatted as `blob` would you? Needs a null value and `%s` for string isn't working.

Comment: Try to use `exit()` to force PHP to die, inside the function call place the output of print_error, there is no way that doesn't output anything nor dies

Answer (score 25):

If you want to get the last error and last query you can use this properties of **$wpdb** object:

```
$wpdb->last_error
```

will show you the last error, if you got one.

```
$wpdb->last_query
```

will assist you with showing the last query (where the error occurred)

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 11):

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32315

One of the columns inputs may be larger than the column is.
Wordpress detects this and will not even send the query to the DB.

The Diff there shows a patch for wp-db you can put in to get more information in the last_error message so it will not be empty.

[image]

Comment: Nice one Liam. Very annoying that WP does not have an error message for this block.

Comment: "One of the columns inputs may be larger than the column is. Wordpress detects this and will not even send the query to the DB." - This helped me with another issue, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully, you have defined the global variable `$wpdb`.

If your `$wpdb` is not working, and also not showing any error then you must try these three steps.

1. Print your error using with errors functions.

   `echo $wpdb->last_error;`

   or

   `echo $wpdb->show_errors;`
2. If no error is visible then you must print your last query using with last query function.

   `echo $wpdb->last_query;`
3. Copy and paste your last query in your Phpmyadmin > Your Database -> Table -> SQL tab, click on the Go button, and you will definitely get proper solutions(errors) in it.

Comment: `show_errors()` doesn't need an `echo`, it simply sets the class to show errors. Errors will appear when we activate this.

Comment: `$wpdb->last_query` is not a method, it's a property. See this entry in the [codex] (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#properties)

Comment: Hey @RafaelAtías, sorry it's my mistake,
Yes, I just corrected it.
Thank you.