# $wpdb->insert() always giving bool(false)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to store data into the newly created table but it always giving me the bool(false) in response. This is strange as I have doing the same code to insert data for more than 4 years and now it is behaving like this, I think I am missing something here. Here is the code.

```
global $wpdb;
$table = wp_emmqebk8se_shippo_order_tracking;
$data = array(
    'object_id' => $shipment->object_id,
    'rate_id' => $shipment->rates[0]->object_id,
    'transaction_id' => $transaction_data->object_id
);
$format = array(
     '%s',
     '%s',
     '%s'
  );
$store_data = $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Database response';
var_dump($data);
var_dump($store_data);
```

What is it here that I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you use wpdb::prepare() before ? Don't know if this is the point here, but I remember that this is more secured at least.

Comment: And what is this : "$table = wp_emmqebk8se_shippo_order_tracking;" ?

 `wp_emmqebk8se_shippo_order_tracking` is a constant ? Else you should have quotes i think

Comment: Sir this is secure because the values coming in data array is coming after many filters so security is not my concern at this point why it is always giving `bool(false)` is my concern sorry if I sound offensive as I don't mean to.

Comment: Tried both the things with quotes and without quotes both of them are not working

Comment: By the way it is the name of the table where data is to be stored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$wpdb->insert not working. No Error Msg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605937/wpdb-insert-not-working-no-error-msg)

Comment: There's no use in guessing. Obtain the actual error, see duplicate. If the code has always been working, the problem is not in the code, but in the database or the input.

Comment: Sir I have tried `$wpdb->print_error()` but no errors are displaying

Comment: i suppose the row is not inserted?

Comment: The database might not be accepting one or more values in the `$data` variable, despite the values are properly escaped. Or that there might be other data that's necessary for the `insert` operation to work properly. Try to add `$wpdb->show_errors();` before the `$wpdb->insert()` line.

Comment: $table = wp_emmqebk8se_shippo_order_tracking; - First, as mentioned above, quotes, this supposed to be a string i guess. Second, i guess  'wp_emmqebk8se_' is prefix, try without it. Third, try direct $wpdb->query. At last, in case it doesn't help, what about passing integers as '%d', not '%s' ?

Comment: @sally thank you your comments helped me alot to understand what I was doing wrong and I resolved it. Thank you so much. Everyone else thank you all for your time and response.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas I'm glad you managed to resolve it. =)