# $wpdb->insert only working on local installation

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I can't figure out why inserting into a database table would work locally, but when uploaded to hosting environment, it doesn't save.

I'm doing this via AJAX as part of a plugin that captures visitor data, and simply stores it to a table so it can be viewed in the backend.

The issue is that on the hosted version, nothing gets saved to the database, and nothing is showing in the view in WP Admin (which simply pulls all rows from the table). However, the admin view is correctly displaying any data from the table if I insert it via phpMyAdmin.

Several functions here, I believe the one in question is the save to database. For a site hosted on 20i, it just doesn't seem to save. No error logs, no console errors.

I can't see any glaring errors I've made (and as I said, this works fine locally). Debugging through the save function locally seems to carry all data correctly, the query seems fine and the result from $wpdb->insert returns as true.

```
// Create Visitors database table on activation
function io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_create() {
    
    // Allow access to the $wpdb variable
    global $wpdb;

    // Set the table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'io_tarot_reading_visitors';
    
    // Set the charset
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    // Create the SQL query
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email varchar(250) NOT NULL,
        url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        date datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta($sql);

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_create');


// Visitor capture database save
function io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_save() {

    // Allow access to the $wpdb variable
    global $wpdb;

    // Set $_POST variables
    $email    = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $url      = sanitize_url($_POST['url']);
    $datetime = $_POST['datetime'];

    // Set table name
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'io_tarot_reading_visitors';

    // Set data to save
    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'url'   => $url,
        'date'  => $datetime
    );

    // Save to database
    $wpdb->insert($table, $data);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_save', 'io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_save');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_save', 'io_tarot_readings_visitors_database_save');


// Export visitor capture data as CSV
function io_tarot_readings_visitors_export_csv() {

    // Check if export button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['visitor-capture-export'])) {

        // Allow access to $wpdb variable
        global $wpdb;
    
        // Set the SQL query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}io_tarot_reading_visitors";
    
        // Get the database rows
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');
    
        // Check if there are existing rows
        if($rows) {
    
            $csv_fields         = array();
            $csv_fields[]       = "first_column";
            $csv_fields[]       = 'second_column';
    
            // Set filename
            $output_filename    = get_bloginfo('name').' - IO Tarot Readings Visitor Data - '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.csv';
            $output_handle      = @fopen('php://output', 'w');
    
            // Set headers
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename);
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
    
            $first = true;
            foreach($rows as $row) {
    
                // Process the header row
                if($first) {
                   $titles = array();
                    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                        $titles[] = $key;
                    }
                    fputcsv($output_handle, $titles);
                    $first = false;
                }
    
                $leadArray = (array) $row;
                
                // Add row to file
                fputcsv($output_handle, $leadArray);
                
            }
        
            // Close output file stream
            fclose($output_handle);
    
            die();
        }

    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'io_tarot_readings_visitors_export_csv');


// Visitor capture database delete
function io_tarot_readings_visitors_delete_data() {

    // Check if delete button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['visitor-capture-delete'])) {

        // Allow access to the $wpdb variable
        global $wpdb;

        // Set table name
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'io_tarot_reading_visitors';

        // Run the SQL query to truncate the table
        $delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE $table");

    }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'io_tarot_readings_visitors_delete_data');
```

Comment: Try to activate the [debug mode](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) of Wordpress which could clearly indicate where the problem is.

Comment: Debug mode won't give me any extra information, as no PHP Errors are occurring. Sadly, this doesn't offer any help, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `nothing is showing in the view in WP Admin`....have you double-checked the relevant database table (e.g. using phpmyadmin) to see if there is a row in there as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided by [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605937/wpdb-insert-not-working-no-error-msg).

> One of the columns inputs may be larger than the column is. Wordpress detects this and will not even send the query to the DB.

In my case, I had the database column for URL set to 55 characters, which was being exceeded on submission, hence no query was being run.

Updated this to a max of 512 characters, and all works fine.